# How can I truncate of a Text displayed in Row in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I display a text on the left of a row, and display tool buttons on the right of the row with Code A.

It's Ok when the text is short, you can see Image A as I expected.

But when the text is long, I find some tool buttons on the right of the row disappeared, you can see Image B.

I hope that tool buttons on the right of the row can be always displayed, and the left text can be truncated automatically when the sapce is not enough.

How can I do ? Thank!

**Code A**

```
Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    )  {

        Text("This a short text")
        
        //Text("This a very long text text text text text text text text")

        Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))

        val iconModifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)

        IconButton(
            enabled = true,
            onClick = {
            }
        ) {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Edit , null, modifier = iconModifier)
        }

        IconButton(
            enabled = true,
            onClick = {
            }
        ) {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Delete , null, modifier = iconModifier)
        }

        IconButton(
            enabled = true,
            onClick = {
            }
        ) {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.ExpandMore , null, modifier = iconModifier)
        }
    }
```

**Image A**

[image]

**Image B**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply to the `Text` the **`weight`** modifier and remove the `Spacer`:

```
     Text("This a very long text text text text text text text text",
          modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
          overflow= TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
          maxLines = 1)

     //Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
```

[image]